# mysql - INNER JOIN - ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I have a query, let's call him Steve.

Steve is supposed insert rows containing data from six columns located in table-1 into table-2, but only pick the rows from table-1 that match values from a column in table-3... AND, if Steve finds any duplicate entries, just update the values in table-2 with the values from table-1.

```
INSERT INTO nht_mlslookup (MSTLISTBRD,MSTMLSNO,MSTACTSTA,MSTSTRNO,MSTSTRNAM,MSTUNITNUM) 
    SELECT (MSTLISTBRD,MSTMLSNO,MSTACTSTA,MSTSTRNO,MSTSTRNAM,MSTUNITNUM) FROM nht_mls AS mls
        INNER JOIN nht_agtdata AS agt ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = agt.agentid
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nht_mlslookup.MSTMLSNO = mls.MSTMLSNO;
```

Problem is...I think I broke Steve?  All he wants to do is this.

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I'm to understand that Steve doesn't do what I ask because a sub-query isn't returning a result, specifically, the `SELECT ...INNER JOIN` statement.

When I'm testing him and ask him to preform:

```
SELECT * FROM jos_mls AS mls
      INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS active ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = active.AGENTUID
```

He does what I expect him to do.

But when I ask him to grab specific columns:

```
SELECT (MSTLISTBRD,MSTMLSNO,MSTACTSTA,MSTSTRNO,MSTSTRNAM,MSTUNITNUM) FROM jos_mls AS mls
    INNER JOIN jos_activeagents AS act ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = act.AGENTUID
```

He gives me the same error.

Any advice on how to instruct Steve to do his job and quit giving me the run around?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis around the field list in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Try to remove the paranthesis around the column list in the SELECT. They are not allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses around the SELECT list are wrong. That makes it be a single expression, but you can't have commas in an expression in SQL.

```
INSERT INTO nht_mlslookup (MSTLISTBRD,MSTMLSNO,MSTACTSTA,MSTSTRNO,MSTSTRNAM,MSTUNITNUM) 
SELECT MSTLISTBRD,MSTMLSNO,MSTACTSTA,MSTSTRNO,MSTSTRNAM,MSTUNITNUM FROM nht_mls AS mls
    INNER JOIN nht_agtdata AS agt ON mls.MSTLISTBRD = agt.agentid
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nht_mlslookup.MSTMLSNO = mls.MSTMLSNO;
```

Comment: Thank you.  Steve has now been put in his place.